# how many times will my program run without running it

Tags: java, math, logging

I'm trying to write a program which uses a form of simulated annealing, though that's not too important

basically I have the following variables:

```
double temperature = 100000;
double coolingrate = 0.99;
double delta = 0.001;
```

I want to work out how to, using Math.log(), calculate the number of times i'll need to run `temperature = temperature * coolingrate` - without actually doing it - until `temperature <= delta`

Comment: `double x = temperature * coolingrate` will always return the same value of `99000.0` and will never approach `delta`.

Comment: Oh I messed it, 1 sec I'll edit

Comment: This is actually a *math* question, not a *programming* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you're trying to find the smallest `n` for which:

[image: Eq. 1]

You can then derive:

[image: Eq. 2]

[image: Eq. 3]

Converted to natural logarithms (used by `Math.log()`):

[image: Eq. 4]

Which would yield the following code (rounding up because your number of iterations has to be an integer number):

```
double n = Math.ceil(Math.log(delta / temperature) / Math.log(coolingrate))
```

For your specified values, that would yield a result of `1833`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!